# start a service in android-aar module from the project

Tags: android, module, android-service, android-library, aar

I implemented an aar file which contains a BLE scanning service. The service uses another aar library. When I try to start the service which is in the aar module. i am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bfonics.android.smartbeaconsupport.service.BLEService at com.bfonics.android.smartbeaconsupport.util.AppManager.startBLEService(AppManager.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` indicates something was there at compiletime but isn't there at runtime.
Rebuild your aar-libraries and make sure that proguard has been disabled.

Comment: still im not getting